# Can't open Printer in RawPrinterHelper Class (ESC/POS)

Tags: c#, printing, escpos, network-printers

I need to use the RawPrinterHelper Class to send commands to a ESC/POS Receipt Printer

> Example of a Command: **0x1D 0x56 0x30** -> cuts the paper

I am using a ESC/POS Printer or rather the Epson TMT20 II and I set it up as a Generic/Text-Only Network Printer

I tried appending the command to the .txt Files that I am printing but it just prints the command not executing them

I access the Printer like this -> \\Server\Printername

> **\\127.0.0.1\PRINTER**

this is how I tried to open and send the commands to the Printer.
**printerName is the path to the Network Printer**

```
string COMMAND = "0x1D 0x56 0x30";

RawPrinterHelper rp = new RawPrinterHelper();
rp.OpenPrint(printerName);
rp.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, COMMAND);
```

when I pass the string containing the Essential Data it returns me Windows Error 1801, I disabled the Firewall but it still returns me that Error.

My Question would be:

> **How do I correctly open a Printer and send Commands to the Printer using the RawPrinterHelper Class, am I using the wrong Format or is there a correct -more efficient way?**

Any Help would be Appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I also tried passing the command like this but the problem must be how I access the Printer
- - -
string GS = Convert.ToString((char)29);
string ESC = Convert.ToString((char)27);
string COMMAND = "";
COMMAND = ESC + "@";
COMMAND += GS + "V" + (char)0;
- - -
GS V 0 is the ASCII Command to cut the paper

https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87#gs_cv

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
it works now,

I just used the Printer Name without the Server Name as the Parameter,
seems like the Method I am using automatically searches for all printers.